# Prevalence Estimates from Observations in data.table Containing Many Binary Classification Columns

Tags: r, data.table

I am doing prevalence estimates from my raw data.table by brute force and I need to be more efficient. Can you help?

My data.table contains one weighted observation per row. There are many columns acting as binary dummy variables indicating if the particular observation belongs to one or more of many possible classifications. (e.g., a story could be 'amazing', 'boring', or 'charming', or any combination of the three.)

There's got to be a `data.table` way to replace my forloop. I also suspect that I might not need to necessarily generate the `queries` set. I appreciate a fresh set of eyes on this problem.

```r
library(data.table)

set.seed(42)
# I have many weighted observations that can be labeled as belonging to one of many categories
# in this example, I simulate 10 observations and only 3 categories
dt = data.table(
        weight = runif( n = 10 , min = 0, max = 1 ),
        a = sample( x = c(0,1) , size = 10 , replace = TRUE ),
        b = sample( x = c(0,1) , size = 10 , replace = TRUE ),
        c = sample( x = c(0,1) , size = 10 , replace = TRUE )
)

# Generate all combinations of categories
queries = as.data.table( expand.grid( rep( list(0:1) , length(names(dt))-1 ) ) )
names(queries) = names(dt)[ 2:length(names(dt)) ] # rename Var1, Var2, Var3 to a, b, c

# Brute force through each possible combination to calculate prevalence
prevalence = rep( NA, nrow(queries) )
for( q in 1:nrow(queries) ){
    prevalence[q] = dt[ a == queries[q, a] & b == queries[q, b] & c == queries[q, c] , sum(weight) ] / dt[ , sum(weight) ]
}

results = copy(queries)
results$prevalence = prevalence

results
```

The output is:

```r
#   a b c prevalence
#1: 0 0 0 0.09771385
#2: 1 0 0 0.10105192
#3: 0 1 0 0.36229784
#4: 1 1 0 0.00000000
#5: 0 0 1 0.00000000
#6: 1 0 1 0.05993197
#7: 0 1 1 0.00000000
#8: 1 1 1 0.37900443
```

> **Updated:** The original question had 42 simulated observations and the data covered each possible combination of categories (a, b, c). The question was revised to only include 10 simulated observations so there would be combinations with no observations (and zero prevalence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### updated answer

#### Method 1:

1. use `CJ` to create the full combination of `a,b,c` then join with `dt` (as in [@TMo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70331296/7522764))
2. sum the `weight` of each group then divide it by `totoal_weight`
3. The appearance of `NA` is rational. You can also fill it by `0` with `nafill` function if you want.

```
total_weight = sum(dt$weight)
dt[CJ(a, b, c, unique = TRUE),  
   on = .(a, b, c)][, 
                    .( prevalence = sum(weight)/total_weight), 
                    by = .(a,b,c)]

#      a     b     c prevalence
#   <num> <num> <num>      <num>
#1:     0     0     0 0.09771385
#2:     0     0     1         NA
#3:     0     1     0 0.36229784
#4:     0     1     1         NA
#5:     1     0     0 0.10105192
#6:     1     0     1 0.05993197
#7:     1     1     0         NA
#8:     1     1     1 0.37900443
```

#### Method2:

```
dt2 = dt[,.( prevalence = sum(weight) / total_weight ), by = .(a,b,c)]
dt2[queries, on = .(a,b,c)]
# or `queries[, prevalence := fcoalesce(dt2[queries, prevalence])]`
#       a     b     c prevalence
#   <int> <int> <int>      <num>
#1:     0     0     0 0.09771385
#2:     1     0     0 0.10105192
#3:     0     1     0 0.36229784
#4:     1     1     0         NA
#5:     0     0     1         NA
#6:     1     0     1 0.05993197
#7:     0     1     1         NA
#8:     1     1     1 0.37900443
```

### original answer

You can calculate it by group

```
dt[,.( prevalence = sum(weight) / dt[,sum(weight)] ), by = .(a,b,c)]
```

- each group corresponds to your categories
- sum the `weight` of each group then divide it by totoal weight

Answer (score 1):

Here are some solutions (in both cases, you can replace `keyby` argument with `by`)

If your dataset (`dt`) already contains all possible combinations of the different categories, then you could do (as in [@Peace Wang solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70331226/10848898))

```
dt[, .(prevalence = sum(weight)/sum(dt$weight)), keyby=.(a, b, c)]

#        a     b     c prevalence
# 1:     0     0     0 0.10876301
# 2:     0     0     1 0.02135357
# 3:     0     1     0 0.03775363
# 4:     0     1     1 0.12806864
# 5:     1     0     0 0.18204696
# 6:     1     0     1 0.15197811
# 7:     1     1     0 0.25629705
# 8:     1     1     1 0.11373903
```

Instead, if the dataset does not contain all possible combinations of the different categories, then you could solve it as follows (`CJ(a, b, c, unique=TRUE)` computes all combinations and remove duplicates)

```
dt[CJ(a, b, c, unique=TRUE), .(prevalence = sum(weight)/sum(dt$weight)), keyby=.(a, b, c), on=.(a, b, c)]

#        a     b     c prevalence
# 1:     0     0     0 0.10876301
# 2:     0     0     1 0.02135357
# 3:     0     1     0 0.03775363
# 4:     0     1     1 0.12806864
# 5:     1     0     0 0.18204696
# 6:     1     0     1 0.15197811
# 7:     1     1     0 0.25629705
# 8:     1     1     1 0.11373903
```

Comment: Good point! I changed the simulated data in the problem so that it would not include each possible combination of categories/classifications (which is more representative of my real problem). However, when I run your solution I only get the non-zero prevalence rows, plus an NA row.
```
    a  b  c prevalence
1: NA NA NA         NA
2:  0  0  0 0.09771385
3:  0  1  0 0.36229784
4:  1  0  0 0.10105192
5:  1  0  1 0.05993197
6:  1  1  1 0.37900443
``` If you make the fix, I will mark your solution as the best.